# Escape double quotes in web.config provider connection string

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config

I have a provider connection string inside my connection string in my web.config, and I don't know how I can use double-quotes for the password.

I try to use something like this for the password: "<>';&

```
 <add name="EntitiesContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Data.Entities.csdl|res://*/Data.Entities.ssdl|res://*/Data.Entities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=DS;Initial Catalog=DB_XY;User ID=USERXY;Password='"<>';&';MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

(of course, this doesn't work like this, but I just wanted to show what I am trying to achieve)

So there is a provider connection string inside the connection string.

I already tried to escape it like this: password='"<>';&' , but it can't handle the """ because it is already used in the outside string.
I also tried to escape it with two quotes ("" and '').

Even the IIS Manager doesn't escape it correctly when I save it as a custom Connection String.

Is there any solution to this?

Thank you & Best regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [web.config and quotes in connectionStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409548/web-config-and-quotes-in-connectionstrings)

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is not quite my problem. If I use "&quot;" inside my password, it will be the ending quote of the connection provider string.

Comment: I think use `\"` to insert double quote.